# Radio Button Custom Styling For Multiple Prompts

Tags: html, css, forms, radio-button

Basically, I am trying to create my own radio button component for react and reuse over again, but I am struggling to get the buttons to work correctly with the styling.  If you select a button in the second set it doesn't react properly even though each set has a different `name` property.  If I get rid of the custom style it works fine.

I think it has something to do with this, but haven't found a solution:

```
.radio-custom {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute; 
}
```

Here is my codepen:

https://codepen.io/Sbphillips19/pen/XLyzzN

HTML:

```
  <form>
        <h2>Radio Button Prompt 1</h2>
        <div>
            <input id="radio-1" class="radio-custom" name="radio-group" type="radio">
            <label for="radio-1" class="radio-custom-label">First Choice</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input id="radio-2" class="radio-custom"name="radio-group" type="radio">
            <label for="radio-2" class="radio-custom-label">Second Choice</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input id="radio-3" class="radio-custom" name="radio-group" type="radio">
            <label for="radio-3" class="radio-custom-label">Third Choice</label>
        </div>
      </div>



 <h2>Radio Button Prompt 2</h2>
        <div>
            <input id="radio-1" class="radio-custom" name="radio-group-2" type="radio">
            <label for="radio-1" class="radio-custom-label">First Choice</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input id="radio-2" class="radio-custom"name="radio-group-2" type="radio">
            <label for="radio-2" class="radio-custom-label">Second Choice</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input id="radio-3" class="radio-custom" name="radio-group-2" type="radio">
            <label for="radio-3" class="radio-custom-label">Third Choice</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

and CSS:

```
.radio-custom {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute; 
}

.radio-custom, .radio-custom-label {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.checkbox-custom-label, .radio-custom-label {
    position: relative;
}

.radio-custom + .radio-custom-label:before {
    content: '';
    background: white;
    border: 2px solid #888888;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 44px;
    height: 44px;
    padding: 2px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.radio-custom:checked + .radio-custom-label:before {
    background: #444444;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 6px #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the attr `id` that should be unique!

Change the following second part of the `html` to this and it will work:

Working example:https://codepen.io/jo-o-teixeira-the-sasster/pen/agQErM

**Radio Button Prompt 2**

```
<div>
        <input id="radio-4" class="radio-custom" name="radio-group-2" type="radio">
        <label for="radio-4" class="radio-custom-label">First Choice</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input id="radio-5" class="radio-custom"name="radio-group-2" type="radio">
        <label for="radio-5" class="radio-custom-label">Second Choice</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input id="radio-6" class="radio-custom" name="radio-group-2" type="radio">
        <label for="radio-6" class="radio-custom-label">Third Choice</label>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I tried that before with just the `id` and didn't realize that the `for` in the label needed to be changed in the label as well.  Thanks